# changing menu css class depends on hash in url

Tags: jquery, css, hash, scroll, slider

I would like to change menu links property (color) depends on which div is in focus on a screen. I am using curtain.js for my project and html looks like this:

```
<div id="menu">
<a href="#section-1">link 1</a>
<a href="#section-2">link 2</a>
<a href="#section-3">link 3</a>
</div>
<ol class="curtains">
<li id="section-1" class="cover">
.....
</li>
<li id="section-2" class="cover">
.....
</li>
<li id="section-3" class="cover">
.....
</li>       
</ol>
```

It is one page layout where each section passes hash to url: if section-1 is in focus then url would be xxx/index.html#section-1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the hash as a selector to target the active element by ID, and then use `siblings()` to set the color on the other li's back to default :

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    $('a[href="'+document.location.hash+'"]').css('color', 'red')
                                             .siblings('a')
                                             .css('color', 'black');
}).trigger('hashchange');
```

**EDIT:**

Seems easier to just change the color on the links when clicked:

```
$('#menu a').on('click', function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'red').siblings('a').css('color', 'black');
})
```

Comment: well, it does what it does but not exactly what I was looking for. Right now script gives siblings a color property, but this color property must be assigned to a links inside #menu

Comment: @user2024679 - Sure, just change the elements, updated my answer, but since you're already clicking those links I don't really see the need to use the hashchange event, it would be easier to just do a regular click event thingy, I'll add one to my answer as well.

Comment: menu acts as a reference, you can scroll one page content as well which makes changes in hash

Comment: in other words you do not click always menu links;)

Comment: Since the hash changes on scroll, that should'nt be a problem if you use the hashchange version, as that will trigger whenever the hash changes.

Comment: ok,but how to make it relevant to hash itself: if #section-1 or #section-3 then menu links are white, otherwise- black?

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you could simply do it that way:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function (e){
 // do color change
});
```

Comment: This is using a jQuery plugin, not built in event.

Comment: @Morpheus - nope, the hashchange event is a javascript event, and it can be accessed like any other event with jQuery, no plugin needed.

Comment: I've just used it in a more complex project and it worked well

Answer (score 1):

using Jquery you should be able to get there.
get the hash first:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
```

then you can add a css class to any element you want using:

```
$('a[href="' + hash + "]').addClass(hash)
```

Didn't try it out myself but give it a go